# customize getItemViewType() of ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter

I have two different types of views for different rows and one view for loading content. For the first rows I want use medicResults1 array and for the other rows I want use medicResults2 array. Until result1 and result2 load, the progress bar loads.

In a tutorial, for one view and for the progress bar, It does this:

```
private static final int ITEM = 0;
private static final int LOADING = 1;
private boolean isLoadingAdded = false;

private List<LastMedicResult1> medicResults1;
private List<LastMedicResult2> medicResults2;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == medicResults1.size() - 1 && isLoadingAdded) ? LOADING : ITEM;
}
```

I could't understand this code. What is the position here? How can I get something like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(medicResults1) return ITEM
    elseif(medicResults2) return ITEM2
    else return LOADING 
}
```

Also xml code is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/main_recycler1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:listitem="@layout/service_list1"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/main_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Also do I must create for second array (medicResults2) another RecyclerView like this?:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/main_recycler2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:listitem="@layout/service_list2"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/main_recycler1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:listitem="@layout/service_list1"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/main_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```